# Issues with dev phone unlock. Constantly getting 0x64 error

Tags: windows-phone-7, jailbreak, unlock

I have an old device, Lumia 800, it was unlocked about a year ago.

Today i restored factory setting on the device and tried to unlock it, but i'm always getting the 0x64.

I tried to:

- reboot the phone,
- reset its factory settings again,
- try to register with turned on/off WiFi / 3G / Location
- run with/without sim-card
- turned off skype

Still nothing helps, any ideas?

PS: i can see a device in my Dashboard, but DevTool returns me 0x64 and phone is still locked.

Comment: Was getting the same error. Couldn't solve it either.

Answer (score 0):

May be you Should UnRegister Your Device from Previous Registration (Dev Center) and Again Try for Registrstion Again. (Keep checking that Your Device's TimeZone is set Properly,Your  Device has Connnectivity to Internet)

Comment: Yep, tried to remove my registration from the DevCenter, that didnt help.

Comment: try to unlock with help of this [Preview for Developers](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/preview-for-developers/178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96)

Comment: Hi, sorry for a long answer. It seems, 800 is not "seeing" `Preview for Developers` on the market.

Answer (score 0):

I advice to reset the phone like it says in http://www.hard-reset.com/nokia-lumia-920-hard-reset.html