# Deploy app on wp7 device

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I install windows phone 8 sdk, but I created project with target version 7.1
When I try deploy app on wp 7 device I get message that the device locked for developer.
I checked my account  on market device is registered there. 
Can I deploy app on this device or is it impossible?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/publicsector/archive/2011/01/04/unlock-your-windows-phone-7-for-development.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the whole process [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Here are the steps but if you encounter any issue while following these steps go the the page linked above to see how to fix your problems.

1. Turn on your phone and unlock the phone screen.
2. On your phone, ensure that the date and time are correct.
3. Connect your phone to your computer by using the USB cable that came with your phone.
4. On your computer’s Start screen, switch to **All apps** view.
5. Under **Windows Phone SDK 8.0**, click **Windows Phone Developer Registration**. The app starts, as shown in the following image. [image: Developer_Registration_Tool]
6. Verify that the **Status** message displays **Identified Windows Phone 8 device. Click the Register button to unlock the phone**.
   If your phone is already registered, the **Status** message indicates this and you see an **Unregister** button.
7. Click **Register**.
8. In the **Sign In** dialog box for your Microsoft account (formerly known as a Windows Live ID), enter the email address and password for your Microsoft account.
   Click **Sign In**.
   If you’re a registered developer, be sure to use the Microsoft account associated with your developer account.
9. After your phone is successfully registered, the **Status** message displays **Congratulations! You have successfully unlocked your Windows Phone.**

### Note: You need to have Zune installed and running with wp7 devices

Comment: Worked for me on a Nokia Lumia 800

Comment: But doesn't work for my wp7. When I tried register my phone I get error code 0x64:"Error communicating with the developer portal. Please set the correct date and time on the phone, check the internet connection and try again later." With date and time all good and wi-fi enabled

Comment: yes,I went back to the factory settings, and again tried to register my WP. But keep getting this message

Comment: What OS do you have on the PC?

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml having exactly the same issue here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833372/issues-with-dev-phone-unlock-constantly-getting-0x64-error ). Have Win 8.1 Pro on my laptop, unlocked second phone successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If Your Device is Registered and not working so You Should Un-Register your Device from Dev Center and Re-Register it.

The Registration Process is Shown  [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2010/12/07/10101849.aspx)  for WP7.

then Try to Deploy app on Device.

Comment: I removed my device from list of devices on my account. And tried registered it again but always get error code 0x64:"Error communicating with the developer portal. Please set the correct date and time on the phone, check the internet connection and try again later." But my device has added in list of phones. But again I can't deploy app